# Prevent sudo from prompting for password when running non-permitted command

Tags: sudo

I have granted a group permission to run certain commands with no password via sudo. When one of the users makes a typo or runs the wrong command the system prompts them for their password and then they get an error. This is confusing for the user so I'd like to just display an error instead of prompting them for a password. Is this possible?

Here is an example of my sudoers file:

```
%mygroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh *
```

Example when they run the wrong script:

```
# sudo /usr/local/bin/otherscript.sh
[sudo] password for user:
Sorry, user user is not allowed to execute '/usr/local/bin/otherscript.sh' as root on <hostname>.
```

Desired output:

```
Sorry, user user is not allowed to execute '/usr/local/bin/otherscript.sh' as root on <hostname>. Please check the command and try again.
```

Note the lack of password prompt.

My google-fu has failed me and only returns results on not asking for a password when the user *is* permitted to run the command.

Comment: If that were possible, it could open a (small) security hole. If you've left yourself logged in and I "borrow" your keyboard, I can't see what commands `sudo` will let you execute without entering your password. With the feature you want, I could get that information for specific commands.

Comment: This is a pretty big security issue.You should not use sudo with scripts as the command. People can just edit the script and run what ever they want totally masking it from an audit. Instead add the call to sudo inside the script.

Comment: What about creating a wrapper around myscript, so the user calls myscriptwrapper, which calls sudo myscript. Then they never even need to know about sudo.

Comment: @coteyr running binary files with `sudo` is just as big of an issue, if users have write access to these files.

Comment: I think mucking with `sudo` in any form is going to lead to trouble.  How about making a copy of all the "allowed" executables, putting the copies in a special directory, and setting all the copies to rwx-x--x- ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's why you use absolute paths to specify allowed programs in sudoers.

Comment: @coteyr BTW, calling sudo from inside the scripts would require you to add programs they call to sudoers. Imagine a script which uses `sed` to modify a config file. Would you really suggest adding `sed` to sudoers?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev no, I would cp /etc/foo /tmp; chmod 777 /tmp/foo; sed /tmp/foo; sudo cp /tmp/foo /etc/foo  then add /usr/bin/cp /tmp/foo /etc/foo to sudoers or better yet just change the permissions on /etc/foo to allow this user access.

Comment: @coteyr That would still let users write whatever they want to `/etc/foo`.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why can't a group be created and assigned to the script directly, with execute permissions, instead of using sudo?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, thats why I suggest just giving that user write permissions in that case. No need for sudo.

Comment: @MartyFried, that doens't work with scripts very well. For example you could just `bash /script/i/should/not/run` and because you have execute on bash you can run the script.

Comment: @coteyr **Not** giving users write access to important files like `/etc/foo` is the very reason `sudo` exists.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, yes, but if your going to use sed or some such for just one file then there is no benefit to sudo. Allowing a user to modify a file is why files have permissions. You don't have to reinvent the wheel. If you want a user to be able to modify a file, then let them. There's no need, or benefit to jump through hoops with sudo to allow a user to modify a file, without a password. You can always just allow them to. Right tool for the right job.

Comment: @coteyr:  I'm not sure I understand.  If you set the execute bits for owner and group, and if the script has the first line `#!/bin/bash`, then you can just enter the script name, and it should work as expected - at least it seemed to in a test on my system.  But perhaps there's more to the OP's problem than what I read that makes this not workable?

Comment: running `/foo.sh` takes execute permissions for both /foo.sh and it's interpreter (bash). Running `bash /foo.sh` only takes execute permissions for bash. Because of that relying on the execute permissions of a script doesn't actually provide anything you can always just run the interpreter.

Comment: @coteyr - so, what if the script only has read permissions set for owner and group?  Then non-root and non-members wouldn't be able to execute it that way either, right?

Comment: @MartyFried so long as the interpreter didn't do anything funny, that is correct.  For example you may get into trouble with that and setuid(). But if you start doing odd stuff like that then there are a lot of doors that need closing.

Comment: @coteyr - Hmmm, and I was thinking that it would be simpler or more straightforward than using the sudo methods. :-(  But I'm not really much of an expert with sudo, and maybe a bit old-fashioned, so perhaps it's only simpler to me. Anyway, sometimes people get stuck on a path, so I thought i'd at least suggest a different one, if applicable.

Comment: It is unfortunate that sudo parameters `-S` (read `sudo` password from `stdin`), and `-n` (non-interactive) cannot be combined. It almost seems like an oversight. Otherwise the `sudo` password could be provided programmatically (via a pipe), while suppressing the prompt with `-n`. But alas, that does not work. When combined, `sudo` simply spits out a message: `sudo: a password is required`, and the piped password is ignored.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From a quick read of `sudo(8)`

```
   -n          The -n (non-interactive) option prevents sudo from
               prompting the user for a password.  If a password is
               required for the command to run, sudo will display an error
               message and exit.
```

And for the doubters:

```
# grep jdoe /etc/sudoers
jdoe    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/echo
#
```

Tested thusly:

```
% sudo echo allowed
allowed
% sudo -n ed             
sudo: a password is required
% sudo ed               

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

Password:
```

So an `alias` for `sudo` for these folks would likely do the trick, to prevent the password prompt. Now why this requires custom compiling `sudo`, I don't know, I just read the manual.

Comment: Indeed. I'd put something like `alias sudo="$(which sudo) -n"` in /etc/bashrc, then use either `sudo` (adjusted behavior) or `command sudo` (default behavior) as desired.

Answer (score 8):

One thing that worked for me, (Sudo version 1.8.17p1), but satisfies only part of your problem, is to set the number of password tries to 0.

```
Defaults:%mygroup passwd_tries = 0
```

This makes sudo exit with code 1 when any command requiring a password is tried. However, it doesn't produce any sort of error message.

Comment: This is also a valid answer but the lack of error message might be confusing. The correct yet unexpected error from the answer above is also confusing though. It's a toss up I guess. Thank you for providing an alternative answer, options are always appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can not.

There is no way to tell who you are until you have authenticated, and, by default you can not authenticate without a password.

You could change authentication to use USB keys, finger print scanners, voice auth, face recognition, or a bunch of other stuff, but the point is the same.

You can not authenticate, with out authenticating **AND** before you authenticate sudo has no business telling you what you can or can not run.

Comment: Typing your password when you run sudo is not identification (“tell who you are”). Sudo knows who you are. Typing your password is presence confirmation.

Comment: I consider presence confirmation as "authentication". As in Authentication, then Authorization.

Comment: The answer says "authentication" not "identification". While sudo does know who you _claim to be,_ based on the user who is logged in on that terminal, it does not know who you _are_ until you have authenticated that identity.

Answer (score 2):

@StrongBad made a comment that deserves to be an answer:

I think the best solution would be to write a wrapper script that always calls `sudo` with the correct parameters. (Including `-n`)

The wrapper script can do argument parsing etc. so that the called sudo script gets as small as possible and therefore less likely to have bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The only way is to change the source code and compile your own fork of `sudo`

Comment: You're right, but I don't think I'm going to get permission to load a custom version of sudo on all of our production servers. hah

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to sudoers file :

```
Defaults        !authenticate
```

It will never ask for user password, but we generally implement sudo like this.

Comment: This disables authentication globally, something the OP did not ask for. _Certain_ commands for _certain_ users should not require password authentication but it is entirely possible that other situations exist where password authentication is required.

Comment: Then you can use something like "Defaults.john !authenticate" if you wish.

Comment: This admittedly doesn't exactly cover the OP's question but answers the title so this answer should be in the list of answers to consider in my opinion